# UNION ALL, semi-overall COUNT, DIFFERENT TABLES

Tags: mysql

I got four table `fiche_visite_autre`, `fiche_visite_dpf`, `fiche_visite` and `Magasin`, in the first three tables I have dates corresponding to the dates when a store was visited.

With this request i get the number of visit in each store from the three tables :

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT fiche_visite_autre.Code_CM as Code_CM, magasin.Nom_Mag, 
COUNT(fiche_visite_autre.Date_Visite) as Nombre_visite, cible_visite.Cible as Cible 
FROM magasin, cible_visite, fiche_visite_autre 
WHERE magasin.Code_CM = cible_visite.Code_CM AND cible_visite.Code_CM = 
fiche_visite_autre.Code_CM GROUP BY fiche_visite_autre.Code_CM

UNION ALL

SELECT fiche_visite_dpf.Code_CM as Code_CM,magasin.Nom_Mag, 
COUNT(fiche_visite_dpf.Date_Visite) as Nombre_visite, cible_visite.Cible as 
Cible
FROM magasin, cible_visite, fiche_visite_dpf 
WHERE magasin.Code_CM = cible_visite.Code_CM AND cible_visite.Code_CM = fiche_visite_dpf.Code_CM GROUP BY fiche_visite_dpf.Code_CM

UNION ALL

SELECT fiche_visite.Code_CM as Code_CM,magasin.Nom_Mag, 
COUNT(fiche_visite.Date_Visite) as Nombre_visite, cible_visite.Cible as Cible 
FROM magasin, cible_visite, fiche_visite
WHERE magasin.Code_CM = cible_visite.Code_CM AND cible_visite.Code_CM = 
fiche_visite.Code_CM GROUP BY fiche_visite.Code_CM) as tmp GROUP BY Code_CM 
ORDER BY Nombre_visite DESC
```

[Table of visit returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qm5Hz.png)

The problem is that I got two time the store 'BAGNOLES DE L'ORNE' in two differents table but only one apear here.

My aim is to got the right number of visit like i got for the store 'NANTERRE' which got 2 visits in the same table.

(Sorry for my english I'm french :)

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the data you're loading from? That would help to have a [minimum, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have answer you

Comment: Great, but you should probably include it as an edit to your original question rather than an answer.

Comment: Yes sorry, i finally find the solution I post it in answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution :

```
SELECT Code_CM, Nom_Mag, SUM(Nombre_visite) as Nombre_visite, Cible FROM (
            SELECT fiche_visite_autre.Date_Visite as DateVisite, fiche_visite_autre.Code_CM as Code_CM, magasin.Nom_Mag as Nom_Mag, COUNT(fiche_visite_autre.Date_Visite) as Nombre_visite, cible_visite.Cible as Cible 
            FROM magasin, cible_visite, fiche_visite_autre 
            WHERE magasin.Code_CM = cible_visite.Code_CM AND cible_visite.Code_CM = fiche_visite_autre.Code_CM GROUP BY Code_CM 

            UNION ALL

            SELECT fiche_visite_dpf.Date_Visite as DateVisite, fiche_visite_dpf.Code_CM as Code_CM,magasin.Nom_Mag as Nom_Mag, COUNT(fiche_visite_dpf.Date_Visite) as Nombre_visite, cible_visite.Cible as Cible
            FROM magasin, cible_visite, fiche_visite_dpf 
            WHERE magasin.Code_CM = cible_visite.Code_CM AND cible_visite.Code_CM = fiche_visite_dpf.Code_CM GROUP BY Code_CM

            UNION ALL

            SELECT fiche_visite.Date_Visite as DateVisite, fiche_visite.Code_CM as Code_CM,magasin.Nom_Mag as Nom_Mag, COUNT(fiche_visite.Date_Visite) as Nombre_visite, cible_visite.Cible as Cible 
            FROM magasin, cible_visite, fiche_visite
            WHERE magasin.Code_CM = cible_visite.Code_CM AND cible_visite.Code_CM = fiche_visite.Code_CM GROUP BY Code_CM
            ) as tmp WHERE DateVisite BETWEEN 'start' AND 'end' GROUP BY Code_CM ORDER BY Nombre_visite DESC
```